# Breeze not returning values set in EF6 interceptors

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

We are using Breeze with Entity Framework 6.  To isolate our tenants, we are using the EF interceptors almost exactly like this post suggests (http://xabikos.com/multitenant/application%20design/software%20as%20a%20service/2014/11/17/create-a-multitenant-application-with-entity-framework-code-first---part-1.html).  So when a new entity is created, the OrganizationId is populated on the server through a IDbCommandTreeInterceptor.  But we’re finding that when the data is updated, Breeze does not return the updated data in SaveResult, even though the value is correctly set in the database.  Here is a subset of the JSON that comes back (captured via Fiddler).

```
{
   "$id":"1",
   "$type":"Breeze.ContextProvider.SaveResult, Breeze.ContextProvider",
   "Entities":[
      {
         "$id":"2",
         "$type":"Ce.Business.Contacts.ContactEntity, Ce.Business",
         "ContactId":32,
         "EventId":"a1dcac14-4332-e511-8269-5cc5d46d497f",
         "Event":null,
         "FirstName":"Test",
         "LastName":"User1",
         "WebsiteUrl":null,
         "OrganizationId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
      }
   ],
   "KeyMappings":[
      {
         "$id":"12",
         "$type":"Breeze.ContextProvider.KeyMapping, Breeze.ContextProvider",
         "EntityTypeName":"Ce.Business.Contacts.ContactEntity",
         "TempValue":-1,
         "RealValue":32
      }
   ],
   "Errors":null
}
```

You can see that the OrganizationId is an empty GUID, even though it is set correctly on the server.  Is there something we need to do to have Breeze return the value that the interceptor changed?  I would have expected that Breeze would return the value from the database and not the value it thinks it will be.